# How to include an image as link for datagrid gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, datagrid

I'm trying to implement the `datagrid gem` in Rails 4 but am not sure how to include a link in the Grid class.

I currently have for the UsersGrid class:

```
class UsersGrid
  include Datagrid

  scope do
    User.order("users.created_at desc")
  end

  column(:avatar) do |user|
    if user.avatar?
      link_to ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag(user.avatar.url, alt: "Profile"), user_path(user)
    else
      link_to ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("profile.gif", alt: "Profile"), user_path(user)
    end
  end
end
```

This generates the following **error message** referring to the `link_to` line :

```
undefined method 'user_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x007f821d3115b8>
```

How should I adjust the code to make the link work?

---

*Additional information:*

View page:

```
<%= datagrid_form_for @grid, :method => :get, :url => users_path %>
<%= will_paginate(@grid.assets) %>
<%= datagrid_table(@grid) %>
<%= will_paginate(@grid.assets) %>
```

Controller method:

```
def index
  @grid = UsersGrid.new(params[:users_grid]) do |scope|
    scope.where(admin: false).page(params[:page]).per_page(30)
  end
  @grid.assets
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution: I had to add `:html => true` to `column(:avatar, :html => true)`. This way html code such as `link_to` work and I also no longer needed `ActionController::Base.helpers` to get access to the `image_tage` method.

Comment: :html => true variable is required so that view helpers are loaded, otherwise they are not. You should mark your own comment as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have a route configured for a user resource in `routes.rb`.

To verify and see what path helpers are available, go to command line, navigate to the project directory, and type in `rake routes`. If properly configured you should see something like:

```
user GET    /users/:id/(.:format) users#show
```

On the far left of the example above is the "Name" which is used to generate the path helper. So in the example above the name is "user" and Rails will automatically generate the helper `user_path` which accepts an argument that is a user's id. So `user_path(1)` is a helper for `/users/1`. If you pass in a User object (like you were in your example) it will just get the id from the User in the background e.g.) `user_path(current_user)` will find the id of current_user and return `/users/1`.

Read more about rake routes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes).

Anyways, if `user` is missing from your `routes.rb` file you could add something like this to `routes.rb`:

```
get '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user
```

Keep in mind you likely already have something for the users resource, so you might be able to make an easier/cleaner change depending on how you have configured the file.

Comment: Thanks Scott, but the route is there. Everything worked when I used regular tables. It's only now that I'm replacing these tables with datagrids that this issue occurs. So it'it has to be related to `datagrid gem`. Also, in views where I also have these paths, the paths work, it's solely this grid class where they don't work.